# ReactJS - cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am practicing React native. When I compile the following program, I am getting Cannot read property 'props' of undefined error for Details.js. Kindly let me know as to what went wrong here.

Layout.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Details from './Details';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state = {
                     heading: "Welcome no-name guy!",
                     header: "I am your header",
                     footer: "I am your footer"
                 };
               }

render() {
   return (
           <div>
            <Header headerprop={this.state.header} />
            <Details detailprop={this.state.heading} />
          </div>
          );
         }
}
```

Details.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Details = (detailprop) => {
 return (
  <div className="heading-style">{this.props.detailprop}</div>
 );
 };
Details.bind(this);
export default Details;
```

Header.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
 render(){
           return(
                   <div>{this.props.headerprop}</div>
                 );
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In functional components, the props are passed as the first parameter.  So, you only need to do this:

```
const Details = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="heading-style">{props.detailprop}</div>
    );
};
```

If you know the prop that you want to handle you can *destructure* that prop:

```
const Details = ({ detailProp }) => {
    return (
        <div className="heading-style">{detailprop}</div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component argument should be props:

```
const Details = (props) => {
 return (
  <div className="heading-style">{props.detailprop}</div>
 );
 };
```

It could be detailprop as you have (or anything for that matter) but you would then need to access the prop by the confusing call:

```
detailprop.detailprop
```

props is the idiomatic approach for React.

Answer (score 0):

Details.js is a stateless functional react component. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

It receives `props` as its argument. You don't need `this` here.

```
import React from 'react';

const Details = (props) => {
 return (
  <div className="heading-style">{props.detailprop}</div>
 );
 };
Details.bind(this); // you don't need this
export default Details;
```

Also, `div` elements will not work for `react-native` . Please refer react native docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/